# How to center content when hidden sidebar in blogger template?

Tags: templates, center, blogger

In my blog, I only wanted my sidebar to show in the homepage so I have used this code on my sidebar widgets to make them disappear (http://www.codeitpretty.com/2013/11/how-to-show-and-hide-blogger-sidebar.html#comment-1621816088):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
</b:if>
```

I had success but the space of the sidebar is still showing like [**so**](http://www.rockandblossom.com/2016/02/how-to-make-your-own-vanilla-extract.html), so now I am trying to center the content, I tried using padding-left and margin-left which works, but then when I make my window smaller, to test the responsiveness, this padding space disturbs the layout.

So I tried with this:

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<style>

.content-blog {
margin-left: 0%; 
}
.sidebar-footer #sidebar-wrapper{
display:none !important; 
}

</style>
</b:if>
```

But the sidebar is still showing.
I hope you can help me find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! replaced the above with:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<style>

#content {
padding-right:0;
}
.content-main {
float:none;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.content-blog {
padding-right:0;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {

float:none;
width:100%;
margin-top:60px;
}

</style>
</b:if>
```